# How to compile a TypeScript library to .mjs and include d.ts?

Tags: typescript, bundler

`tsc` nearly works but I can't get it to output `.mjs` files. `swc` doesn't want to output `.mjs` *nor* the `.d.ts` files.

Is there a comprehensive bundler that'll do both?

Ideally I want to point it at my `index.ts` file which just looks like this

```
export * from './map'
export * from './set'
export * from './array'
```

And then it will find the other files and compile them. Anything not in the import/export chain should be omitted from the output, but if I have to compile my entire `src` dir I can live with that.

---

Additional constraints:

- The compiled JS should include file extensions in its import/export statements: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68783000/65387

  - I don't want to include `.js` in my *source* code when trying to import a `.ts` file (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62626938/65387)

I think I can work around the `.mjs` file extension by adding `"type": "module"` to `package.json`. But I still need the import/export statements to be re-written properly (with extension)

Comment: Did you see this https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18442#issuecomment-1073060190 ?

Comment: Yeah, I saw that comment a few minutes ago and `swc` isn't working for me either (2nd sentence of my Q)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I got it. The answer is Rollup.

```bash
yarn add --dev rollup @rollup/plugin-typescript @rollup/plugin-terser tslib
```

```js
// rollup.config.js
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import terser from '@rollup/plugin-terser';

export default {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: {
        dir: 'dist',
        format: 'esm',
        entryFileNames: '[name].mjs'
    },
    plugins: [
        typescript(),
        terser({
            format: {
                comments: 'some',
                beautify: true,
                ecma: '2022',
            },
            compress: false,
            mangle: false,
            module: true,
        }),
    ]
};
```

```json
// package.json
{
  "name": "@you/your-package",
  "version": "0.1.11",
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.3.1",
  "main": "dist/index.mjs",
  "type": "module",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "/dist"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "test": "jest --silent=false",
    "publish-patch": "npm version patch && hg ci -m \"Publish v$(jq -r '.version' package.json)\" && npm publish"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-terser": "^0.2.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^10.0.1",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.4",
    "jest": "^29.3.1",
    "rollup": "^3.9.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.3",
    "tslib": "^2.4.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  }
}
```

That will output files with `.mjs` extension and include the `.d.ts` files and omit other junk in your `src` dir like test files.

Terser is needed if you want to strip comments from the output. The import/export file extension renaming is no longer relevant because Rollup insists on outputting a single file.

`tslib` is needed to make rollup happy. So is `type: "module"` even though TS doesn't care, and nor does Node if you use `.mjs` extension.