# How to import external javascript file in the main.js, can we access the external file using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json, node-modules

Here, I'm exporting the countries array in the **external javascript file.**

```
const countries = [
  "Albania",
  "Bolivia",
  "Canada",
  "Denmark",
  "Ethiopia",
  "Finland",
  "Germany",
  "Hungary",
  "Ireland",
  "Japan",
  "Kenya",
];
export default countries;
```

Now, I'm importing and console log it in my main.js file

```
import countries from "./countries";
console.log(countries);
```

But, Why I'm receiving the **error**

```
node:internal/errors:484
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error \[ERR\_MODULE\_NOT\_FOUND\]: Cannot find module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65384754/error-err-module-not-found-cannot-find-module)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you are using ECMAScript Modules in your project make sure to specify the file type extension.**

**In your case try changing :**

```
import countries from "./countries";
```

**To :**

```
import { countries } from "./countries.js";
```

**Keep in mind that both are correct when it comes to the common javascript based approach.**