Typescript/Node.js file extensions - 'module not found' when trying to run the app
I'm facing a problem with the configuration of my node.js/typescript project. The imports need extensions otherwise I got an error - 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'. But if include .ts to them then i will need to include "allowImportingTsExtensions" along with "noEmit" in tsconfig.json then if include them "npm run build" wouldn't compile anything (it doesn't create 'dist' folder' because of noEmit ?? ). It has been hell of a circle for me and I don't know how to get out of it so it finally works lol.
PS: There is a second problem - My project have two folders "client" with tsx/jsx code and "server" with nodejs/typescript. When I compile from the server folder with npx tsc (npm run build) it creates a 'dist' folder with two different builds - client and server? Why? I run it from the server folder, shouldnt it create only for it? How I managed to create a build of the client from the server :D ? It bugs my structure as I need only the build of the server directly in the dist folder without creating anything else.
HERE are the examples of my code ->
Imports which give an err "ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND":


import indexRouter from "./routes/indexRouter";
import testRouter from "./routes/testRouter";
import loginRouter from "./routes/loginRouter";



package.json (server folder) :


{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npx tsc",
    "start": "node dist/server/index.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npx tsc --watch\" \"nodemon -q dist/server/index.js\"",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.15",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "concurrently": "^8.2.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "google-auth-library": "^9.11.0",
    "googleapis": "^140.0.0",
    "http-errors": "^2.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "mongodb": "^6.7.0",
    "mongoose": "^8.4.1",
    "mongoose-gridfs": "^1.3.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "multer-gridfs-storage": "^5.0.2",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.14",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-helmet-async": "^2.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.23.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.6",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.17",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/gridfs-stream": "^0.5.39",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.6",
    "@types/mongodb": "^4.0.7",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.11.97",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.11",
    "@types/node": "^20.14.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@types/react-helmet": "^6.1.11",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "concurrently": "^8.2.2",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0",
    "typescript": "^5.5.2",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2"
  }
}



tsconfig.json (server folder):


{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
  },
  "include": ["./**/*"],
  "exclude": [
    "../client",
    "../client/**/*",
    "./dist",
    "./node_modules"
  ]
}




When you use "modules", you must import with full file extensions. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65384754/error-err-module-not-found-cannot-find-module
